# How to simulate mouse move in D3 so when you drag nodes, other nodes move automatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I have a sticky force layout : http://jsfiddle.net/smqsusdw/

I have this function that drags one node to a position :

```
function positionnodes(){

     force.stop();
     node.each(function(d, i){
         if(i===1){      

         d.fixed = true;
         d.x = 100;
         d.y = 100;
         }
     }).transition().duration(1000).attr("cx", function(d){ return d.x }).attr("cy", function(d){ return d.y });

    link.transition().duration(1000)
                      .attr("x1", function (d) {        return d.source.x;  })
                      .attr("y1", function (d) {        return d.source.y;  })
                      .attr("x2", function (d) {        return d.target.x;  })
                      .attr("y2", function (d) {        return d.target.y;  });

}
```

Now when it does this I want it to look like I am dragging it with my mouse. But when I press the button only the chosen node moves. Is there anyway to simulate a mousedrag on the node so that the other related nodes seem to move with it ?

For example, I press the button, only one node moves and all the others stay put.

But when I drag one of the nodes to a position the related nodes kind of move with it due to the D3 force physics. Is there a way to simulate this movement

Comment: Also when I drag the node after it moves the node seems to go back to its previous position. I think this is due to when you call force.drag it starts the force physics again. I want to be able to simulate mousemove without using my mouse so to speak

Comment: Any property of the [`mousemove`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mousemove) event is "Read only". Hower it might work for you, if you first move the chosen node and then trigger the `mousemove` event on it (the node should be the target). Just an idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To choose the right approach it is important to know that in D3's force layout the calculations are decoupled from the actual rendering of any elements. [`d3.layout.force()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#force) will take care of calculating movements and positions according to the specified parameters. The rendering will be done by the handler registered with `.force("tick", renderingHandler)`. This function will get called by the force layout on every tick and render the elements based on the calculated positions.

With this in mind it becomes apparent, that your solution will not work as expected. Using transitions on the graphical elements will just move the nodes around without updating the data and without any involvement of the force layout. To get the desired behavior, you need to stick to the decoupling of calculations and rendering. This will free you from the need to implement a simulation of mouse events.

This could be done by using a [`d3.timer()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#d3_timer), which will repeatedly invoke a function setting the moving node's position to the interpolated values between its start and end values. After having set these values, the function will activate the force layout to do its work for the rest of the nodes and invoke the rendering handler `.tick()`, which will update the entire layout.

```
function positionnodes(){

    var move = graph.nodes[1],  // the node to move around
        duration = 1000,        // duration of the movement
        finalPos = { x: 100, y: 100 },
        interpolateX = d3.interpolateNumber(move.x, finalPos.x),
        interpolateY = d3.interpolateNumber(move.y, finalPos.y);

    // We don't want the force layout to mess with our node.
    move.fixed = true;  

    // Move the node by repeatedly determining its position.
    d3.timer(function(elapsed) {

        // Because the node should remain fixed, the previous position (.px, .py)
        // needs to be set to the same value as the new position (.x, .y). This way
        // the node will not have any inherent movement.
        move.x = move.px = interpolateX(elapsed / duration); 
        move.y = move.py = interpolateY(elapsed / duration); 

        // Re-calculate the force layout. This will also invoke tick()
        // which will take care of the rendering.
        force.start();

        // Terminate the timer when the desired duration has elapsed.
        return elapsed >= duration;
    });

}
```

Have a look at the following snippet or the updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/smqsusdw/1/) for a working adaption of your code.

```js
var graph  ={
  "nodes": [
    {"x": 469, "y": 410},
    {"x": 493, "y": 364},
    {"x": 442, "y": 365},
    {"x": 467, "y": 314},
    {"x": 477, "y": 248},
    {"x": 425, "y": 207},
    {"x": 402, "y": 155},
    {"x": 369, "y": 196},
    {"x": 350, "y": 148},
    {"x": 539, "y": 222},
    {"x": 594, "y": 235},
    {"x": 582, "y": 185},
    {"x": 633, "y": 200}
  ],
  "links": [
    {"source":  0, "target":  1},
    {"source":  1, "target":  2},
    {"source":  2, "target":  0},
    {"source":  1, "target":  3},
    {"source":  3, "target":  2},
    {"source":  3, "target":  4},
    {"source":  4, "target":  5},
    {"source":  5, "target":  6},
    {"source":  5, "target":  7},
    {"source":  6, "target":  7},
    {"source":  6, "target":  8},
    {"source":  7, "target":  8},
    {"source":  9, "target":  4},
    {"source":  9, "target": 11},
    {"source":  9, "target": 10},
    {"source": 10, "target": 11},
    {"source": 11, "target": 12},
    {"source": 12, "target": 10}
  ]
}





var width = 960,
    height = 500;

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .size([width, height])
    .charge(-400)
    .linkDistance(40)
    .on("tick", tick);

var drag = force.drag()
    .on("dragstart", dragstart);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var link = svg.selectAll(".link"),
    node = svg.selectAll(".node");

//d3.json("graph.json", function(error, graph) {
 // if (error) throw error;

  force
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .links(graph.links)
      .start();

  link = link.data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "link");

  node = node.data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("r", 12)
      .on("dblclick", dblclick)
      .call(drag);
//});

function tick() {
  link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

  node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
}

function dblclick(d) {
  d3.select(this).classed("fixed", d.fixed = false);
}

function dragstart(d) {
  d3.select(this).classed("fixed", d.fixed = true);
}


function positionnodes(){
    
    var move = graph.nodes[1],  // the node to move around
        duration = 1000,        // duration of the movement
        finalPos = { x: 100, y: 100 },
        interpolateX = d3.interpolateNumber(move.x, finalPos.x),
        interpolateY = d3.interpolateNumber(move.y, finalPos.y);
    
    // We don't want the force layout to mess with our node.
    move.fixed = true;  
    
    // Move the node by repeatedly determining its position.
    d3.timer(function(elapsed) {
        
        // Because the node should remain fixed, the previous position (.px, .py)
        // needs to be set to the same value as the new position (.x, .y). This way
        // the node will not have any inherent movement.
        move.x = move.px = interpolateX(elapsed / duration); 
        move.y = move.py = interpolateY(elapsed / duration); 
        
        // Re-calculate the force layout. This will also invoke tick()
        // which will take care of the rendering.
        force.start();
        
        // Terminate the timer when the desired duration has elapsed.
        return elapsed >= duration;
    });
 
}
```

```css
.link {
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node {
  cursor: move;
  fill: #ccc;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node.fixed {
   fill: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<button onclick = 'positionnodes()'> click me</button>
```

Comment: Brilliant. Perfect solution and informative answer. If i could upvote it more I would. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

I was playing around with this so I thought I may as well post it as well.
@altocumulus was too fast for me!

Here is a way to do a very similar thing but **using a transition**.  This allows you to access easing, delays and chaining for free as well, so it's easy to generalise to a more complex set of movements.

#### Using a transition on dummy node as a timer

1. Create a dummy node with an exclusive namespace (so it won't be rendered) and put a transition on it.
2. Define getters for `px` and `py` on the chosen data element, to transparently hook up with the transition, by returning the fake `cx` and `cy` attributes of the dummy node while they are transitioning.
3. Call dragstart on the selected node.
4. On the `end` event of the transition, clean up by replacing the getters with the current value of the dummy node attributes.
5. Wrap this structure in a d3 selection so that it can be generalised to an arbitrary subset of the nodes.
6. Use the javascript Array.prototype.reduce method to chain an arbitrary number of transitions.

You can keep clicking the button and it sends the node to random locations.

If you generate the dummy nodes using d3 style data binding then you can easily generalise it to move any number of nodes in unison.  In the following example they are filtered on the `fixed` property.

```js
var graph  ={
        "nodes": [
            {"x": 469, "y": 410},
            {"x": 493, "y": 364},
            {"x": 442, "y": 365},
            {"x": 467, "y": 314},
            {"x": 477, "y": 248},
            {"x": 425, "y": 207},
            {"x": 402, "y": 155},
            {"x": 369, "y": 196},
            {"x": 350, "y": 148},
            {"x": 539, "y": 222},
            {"x": 594, "y": 235},
            {"x": 582, "y": 185},
            {"x": 633, "y": 200}
        ],
        "links": [
            {"source":  0, "target":  1},
            {"source":  1, "target":  2},
            {"source":  2, "target":  0},
            {"source":  1, "target":  3},
            {"source":  3, "target":  2},
            {"source":  3, "target":  4},
            {"source":  4, "target":  5},
            {"source":  5, "target":  6},
            {"source":  5, "target":  7},
            {"source":  6, "target":  7},
            {"source":  6, "target":  8},
            {"source":  7, "target":  8},
            {"source":  9, "target":  4},
            {"source":  9, "target": 11},
            {"source":  9, "target": 10},
            {"source": 10, "target": 11},
            {"source": 11, "target": 12},
            {"source": 12, "target": 10}
        ]
    }

    var width = 500,
        height = 190,
        steps = function(){return +d3.select("#steps-selector").property("value")};

    var force = d3.layout.force()
        .size([width, height])
        .charge(-100)
        .linkDistance(6)
        .on("tick", tick);

    var drag = force.drag()
        .on("dragstart", dragstart);

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

    var link = svg.selectAll(".link"),
        node = svg.selectAll(".node");

    //d3.json("graph.json", function(error, graph) {
    // if (error) throw error;

    force
        .nodes(graph.nodes)
        .links(graph.links)
        .start();

    link = link.data(graph.links)
        .enter().append("line")
        .attr("class", "link");

    node = node.data(graph.nodes)
        .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("r", 6)
        .on("dblclick", dblclick)
        .call(drag);
    //});

    function tick() {
        link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
            .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
            .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
            .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

        node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
            .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
        force.alpha(0.1)
    }

    function dblclick(d) {
        d3.select(this).classed("fixed", d.fixed = false);
    }

    function dragstart(d) {
        d3.select(this).classed("fixed", d.fixed = true);
    }


    function positionnodes(){
        var ns = "CB:emit/drag/transition/or-whatever-you-feel-like",
            shadowNodes = d3.select("body").selectAll("emitDrag")
                .data(graph.nodes.filter(function(d){return d.fixed})),
            shadowedData = [];
        shadowNodes.enter().append(function(){return document.createElementNS(ns, "emitDrag")});

        shadowNodes.each(function(d, i){
            var n = d3.select(this);
            shadowedData[i] = d;
            dragstart.call(node.filter(function(s){return s === d;}).node(), d);

            d.fixed = true;
            n.attr({cx: d.x, cy: d.y});

            Object.defineProperties(d, {
                px: {
                    get: function() {return +n.attr("cx")},
                    configurable: true
                },
                py: {
                    get: function() {return +n.attr("cy")},
                    configurable: true
                }
            });
        });

        force.start();

        d3.range(steps()).reduce(function(o, s){
            return o.transition().duration(750).ease("cubic")
                    .attr({
                        cx: function(){return (1+3*Math.random())*width*0.2},
                        cy: function(){return (1+3*Math.random())*height*0.2}
                    })
        },shadowNodes)

            .each("end", function(d, i){
                var n = d3.select(this);
                Object.defineProperties(shadowedData[i], {
                    px: {value: +n.attr("cx"), writable: true},
                    py: {value: +n.attr("cy"), writable: true}
                });
            });
    }
```

```css
body {
            margin: 0;
        }
        .link {
            stroke: #000;
            stroke-width: 1.5px;
        }

        .node {
            cursor: move;
            fill: #ccc;
            stroke: #000;
            stroke-width: 1.5px;
        }

        .node.fixed {
            fill: #f00;
        }
        button, input {display: inline-block}
        .input {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            /*white-space: pre;*/
            margin: 0;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>
<div class="input">
    <button onclick = 'positionnodes()'> select the nodes to include then click me</button>
    steps <input id="steps-selector" onchange = 'positionnodes()' type="number"  name="steps" value = 3 min="1" max="100"/>
</div>
```

---

#### EDIT

Here are a few more possibilities, all due to the power of d3 transitions...

```js
    var graph  ={
        "nodes": [
            {"x": 469, "y": 410, move: true},
            {"x": 493, "y": 364},
            {"x": 442, "y": 365},
            {"x": 467, "y": 314},
            {"x": 477, "y": 248, move: true},
            {"x": 425, "y": 207},
            {"x": 402, "y": 155},
            {"x": 369, "y": 196},
            {"x": 350, "y": 148},
            {"x": 539, "y": 222},
            {"x": 594, "y": 235},
            {"x": 582, "y": 185},
            {"x": 633, "y": 200, move: true}
        ],
        "links": [
            {"source":  0, "target":  1},
            {"source":  1, "target":  2},
            {"source":  2, "target":  0},
            {"source":  1, "target":  3},
            {"source":  3, "target":  2},
            {"source":  3, "target":  4},
            {"source":  4, "target":  5},
            {"source":  5, "target":  6},
            {"source":  5, "target":  7},
            {"source":  6, "target":  7},
            {"source":  6, "target":  8},
            {"source":  7, "target":  8},
            {"source":  9, "target":  4},
            {"source":  9, "target": 11},
            {"source":  9, "target": 10},
            {"source": 10, "target": 11},
            {"source": 11, "target": 12},
            {"source": 12, "target": 10}
        ]
    }

    var width = 500,
        height = 190,
        steps = function(){return +d3.select("#steps-selector").property("value")};

    var inputDiv = d3.select("#input-div"),
        tooltip = (function tooTip() {
            var tt = d3.select("body").append("div")
                .attr("id", "tool-tip")
                .style({
                    position: "absolute",
                    color: "black",
                    background: "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
                    display: "none"
                });
            return function(message) {
                return message ?
                       function() {
                           var rect = this.getBoundingClientRect();
                           tt
                               .style({
                                   top: (rect.bottom + 6) + "px",
                                   left: (rect.right + rect.left) / 2 + "px",
                                   width: "10px",
                                   padding: "0 1em 0 1em",
                                   background: "#ccc",
                                   'border-radius': "2px",
                                   display: "inline-block"
                               })
                               .text(message)
                       }:
                       function() {
                           tt
                               .style({
                                   display: "none"
                               })
                       }
            }
        })(),
        easeings = ["linear", "quad", "cubic", "sin", "exp", "circle", "elastic", "back", "bounce"],
        xEase = d3.ui.select({
            base: d3.select("#input-div"),
            oninput: positionnodes,
            data: easeings,
            initial: "bounce",
            onmouseover: tooltip("x"),
            onmouseout: tooltip()
        }),
        yEase = d3.ui.select({
            base: d3.select("#input-div"),
            oninput: positionnodes,
            data: easeings,
            initial: "circle",
            onmouseover: tooltip("y"),
            onmouseout: tooltip()
        }),
        t = (function(){
            var s = d3.select("#input-div").selectAll(".time")
                .data([{name: "tx", value: 0.75}, {name: "ty", value: 1.6}])
                .enter().append("input")
                .attr({
                    id: function(d){return d.name + "-selector"},
                    type: "number",
                    name: function(d){return d.name},
                    value: function(d){return d.value},
                    min: "0.1", max: "5", step: 0.5
                })
                .on("change", positionnodes)
                .each(function(d){
                    d3.select(this).on("mouseover", tooltip(d.name))
                })
                .on("mouseout", tooltip());
            return function(){
                var values = [];
                s.each(function(){
                    values.push(d3.select(this).property("value") * 1000);
                });
                return  values;
            }
        })();


    var force = d3.layout.force()
        .size([width, height])
        .charge(-100)
        .linkDistance(6)
        .on("tick", tick);

    var drag = force.drag()
        .on("dragstart", dragstart);

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

    var link = svg.selectAll(".link"),
        node = svg.selectAll(".node");

    //d3.json("graph.json", function(error, graph) {
    // if (error) throw error;

    force
        .nodes(graph.nodes)
        .links(graph.links)
        .start();

    link = link.data(graph.links)
        .enter().append("line")
        .attr("class", "link");

    node = node.data(graph.nodes)
        .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("r", 6)
        .on("dblclick", dblclick)
        .call(drag);
    //});

    function tick() {
        link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
            .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
            .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
            .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

        node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
            .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
        force.alpha(0.1)
    }

    function dblclick(d) {
        d3.select(this).classed("fixed", d.move = false);
    }

    function dragstart(d) {
        d3.select(this).classed("fixed", d.move = true);
    }


    function positionnodes(){
        var ns = "CB:emit/drag/transition/or-whatever-you-feel-like",
            transitions = d3.select("body").selectAll("transitions")
                .data([graph.nodes.filter(function(d){return d.move})]),
            transitionsEnter = transitions.enter().append(function(){
                return document.createElementNS(ns, "transitions")
            }),
            shadowNodes = transitions.selectAll("emitDrag")
                .data(function(d){return d}),
            shadowedData = [];
        shadowNodes.enter().append(function(){
            return document.createElementNS(ns, "emitDrag")
        });

        shadowNodes.each(function(d, i){
            var n = d3.select(this);
            shadowedData[i] = d;
            dragstart.call(node.filter(function(s){return s === d;}).node(), d),
            endAll = d3.cbTransition.endAll();

            n.attr({cx: d.x, cy: d.y});

            Object.defineProperties(d, {
                px: {
                    get: function() {return d.x = +n.attr("cx")},
                    configurable: true
                },
                py: {
                    get: function() {return d.y = +n.attr("cy")},
                    configurable: true
                }
            });
        });

        force.start();
        d3.range(steps()).reduce(function(o){
            return (o.transition("cx").duration(t()[0]).ease(xEase.value())
                .attr({
                    cx: function(d){
//                        return d.x + (Math.random() - 0.5) * width/5
                        return (1+3*Math.random())*width*0.2
                    }
                }))
        },shadowNodes)

            .call(cleanUp, "px", "cx");

        d3.range(steps()).reduce(function(o){
            return (o.transition("cy").duration(t()[1]).ease(yEase.value())
                .attr({
                    cy: function(d){
//                        return d.y + (Math.random() - 0.5) * height/5
                        return (1+3*Math.random())*height*0.2
                    }
                }))
        },shadowNodes)

            .call(cleanUp, "py", "cy");

        function cleanUp(selection, getter, attribute){
            selection.each("end.each", function(d, i){
                var n = d3.select(this);
                Object.defineProperty(shadowedData[i], getter, {
                    value: +n.attr(attribute), writable: true
                });
            })
                .call(endAll, function(){
                    transitions.remove();
                }, "move-node");

        }
    }
    positionnodes()
```

```css
body {
            margin: 0;
            position: relative;
        }
        .link {
            stroke: #000;
            stroke-width: 1.5px;
        }

        .node {
            cursor: move;
            fill: #ccc;
            stroke: #000;
            stroke-width: 1.5px;
        }

        .node.fixed {
            fill: #f00;
        }
        button, input {display: inline-block}
        .input-div {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            /*white-space: pre;*/
            margin: 0;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/cool-Blue/d3-lib/master/transitions/end-all/1.0.0/endAll.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/cool-Blue/d3-lib/master/inputs/select/select.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
<div id="input-div">
    <button onclick = 'positionnodes()'> select the nodes to include then click me</button>
    steps <input id="steps-selector" onchange = 'positionnodes()' type="number"  name="steps" value = 10 min="1" max="100"/>
</div>
```

Comment: that's really cool :)) I like the way you have used random waypoints and the capability of moving more than one node at once :)) Really nice example. As you said 'altocumulus' was too fast but appreciate your input. Nice to see a solution from different angles :))

Comment: @thisOneGuy the key is the transitions on dummy nodes plus getters on the data elements. It unlocks all of the power of d3 data binding and transitions.  If you play around with different easing functions and different times for x and y movements, you can get a sort of Kung Fu motion :P

Comment: wow, another update. I love how carried away you got, I am exactly the same :L