# Move force diagram node with transition

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

I was wondering if anyone could help with this:

I have a simple d3 force diagram ([here](http://jsfiddle.net/yeQS2/94/)). I was wondering if I programmatically can get a node (fixed node C1) and shift it to a different position with transition animation like in the follwoing example:

```
    var mySquare=svg.append("rect")
      .attr("x",60)
      .attr("y",60)
      .attr("width",60)
      .attr("height",60);

    mySquare
  .transition()
  .attr("x",320);
```

So in a nutshell - once a diagram completes I would like to pick a node (C1) and give different x and y using a transition animation.

Comment: You just need to set the new attributes with a transition, given that it's fixed already. `node.transition().attr("cx", ...).attr("cy", ...)`

Comment: Hey Lars, thanks for your reply. I did try that, but it didn't work. I'll put together a small example of what I did maybe I'm just missing something super obvious. Thanks.

Comment: @Lars Kotthoff , [heres an example](http://jsfiddle.net/yeQS2/377/) of what You proposed earlier. Either its wrong node object im calling transition on or im missing something here. Thanks

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32998608/2670182) might give you some ideas. I suggest reading the accepted answer first to introduce yourself to the idea. The general strategy is to drive it through the data and use transitions on dummy nodes to evolve the data.

Comment: @NeilVarnas You need to select the actual element, not the data, and then transition the right attributes. https://jsfiddle.net/yeQS2/378/ does that -- the connections need to be updated as well, but I'm sure you can figure that out.

Comment: Both of You are right, Thank You Lars, but I think @CoolBlue had a more thorough direction to an answer. If You could create that as a seperate post Ill mark it as an answer

Comment: If it was useful to you, just upvote my answer in the other thread, no need to clutter things up here by posting more or less the same answer. :)

Comment: Sorted, thanks again